VB,net cannot assign the number 18446744073709551615 to a Uint64 or Uint128
In a tool of my I run into this very high number what seems to be a uInt64.
So, I thought if I'm using a uInt128 it should work but is also generate an overflow.
How I can overcome this?
Kind regards,
Johan
I'm trying to get this value assigned with in vb.net
I tried uLong, uInt64, uInt128 but all gave an overflow.

What happens if you UInt128.Parse("18446744073709551615")?

Show us the code. I'll wager that it has nothing to do with those types and you're actually trying to use an Int32 literal and that's causing the overflow. We can't know if we can't see what you're doing though. We should NEVER have to ask you to show us the relevant code. It's a given for any programming question but especially here.

I've answered this question despite the fact that it's missing significant relevant information, because I think I can be fairly sure of what the issue is. That won't always be the case though. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a question properly on SO. That will always include a FULL and CLEAR description of the problem, e.g. whether it's a compilation error or a run time exception, and the simplest code that demonstrates the issue. You should have taken the site tour when prompted.

I'd be willing to bet that you have done something like this:
Dim n1 As UInt128 = 18446744073709551615
Dim n2 As UInt64 = 18446744073709551615

and, in both cases, the literal value is flagged as a compilation error. As I suggested in the comments, that has nothing at all to do with the UInt64 or UInt128 types. In code, if you write a literal numeric value, the type of that value will default to Integer/Int32 if it has no decimal point and Double if it does. Obviously, the value 18446744073709551615 cannot fit into the Integer/Int32 data type so you get an overflow error.
If you want to make a numeric literal a type other than those defaults, you need to use an appropriate suffix. In this case, you can use UL to force the literal to be type ULong/UInt64. This code works without issue:
Dim n1 As UInt128 = 18446744073709551615UL
Dim n2 As UInt64 = 18446744073709551615UL

You should check the documentation to see what all the valid suffixes are but you can probably guess, keeping in mind that they are based on the native VB data type names, rather than the .NET types.

You're right, putting UL solved the issue.

There ought to be an existing dupe target for this, I know we've answered questions about it before.

@JohanValstar, if an answer resolves your issue, be sure to accept it, so everyone can see that you need no more help without having to open the question and read. That's another point covered in the Help Center.
